# inserting more elements to top of page without changing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a webpage that displays a list of text messages.

When the user scrolls all the way to the top, i.e. when `window.pageYOffset === 0`, the page will make an API call to fetch more messages.

Those older messages will be inserted into the list and therefore on top of the page. When this happens, the newly inserted messages should be out of view, so that the content on the page  should not change. In other words, `window.pageYOffset` should no longer be zero. And the user would have to scroll up more in order to see the newly inserted messages.

How can I do this in React?

his is what I have so far, which works, but it calls 2 scroll functions directly one after the other.

`msg_ref` is the first element in the list before the loading of more messages.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      msg_ref.current?.scrollIntoView({});
      // offset needed due to sticky navbar and other stuff
      window.scrollBy({ top: is_mobile ? -180 : -195 });
  }, [when_more_msgs_are_loaded]);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and what you have so far? Is not really easy to know what's the best fitting solution gor your case without seeing your code.

Comment: example added..